# Is there a gender-neutral version for expressions like "sister site"?

Tags: single-word-requests, grammar, word-usage, grammatical-gender

I have [recently seen](https://politics.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/34872) "sister site" being used and I am wondering if there is a gender-neutral equivalent for it.

In my native language (Romanian) expressions like "brother X" or "sister Y" feel natural because the language is gendered and there is a gender match (although the "sister" tends to be used more often despite the noun gender).

I am thinking of *sibling* as a replacement, but I am not sure about it.

**Question:**  Is there a gender-neutral version for expressions like "sister site"?

Comment: Related: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/369932/usage-and-origin-of-sister-in-expressions-like-sister-company-sister-ship-s

Comment: What specifically do you mean by "sister site"? One owned by the same company?

Comment: @StuartF I mean a site run under the same umbrella/group of sites. Example: *.stackexchange. the same company runs com sites. Generally, speaking any entity that can be placed in a tree like hierarchy and has a common "parent" with another has a sibling entity,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Companion site. Or partner site

These two neutral expressions convey what you are trying to achieve.

Companion implies you own it. Partner has the sense that another company owns it.

Definition:

Partner: a company or organisation you are closely involved with, in some way.

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/partner