# What do you call the home in which you grew up and spent most of your childhood: father home, mother home or what?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Your native country is your ["motherland"](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/motherland)/ "fatherland",  the land of your ancestors is your ["fatherland"](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/fatherland) and your first language is your ["mother tongue"](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/mother-tongue).

**What do you call the home in which you grew up and spent most of your childhood** (any other mother/father-containing word or phrase such as father home, mother home, maternal home, paternal home, or ___)?

I want to use it in sentences like these:

> - "When I was single and still living in my ___, I didn't eat meat food at all, but after getting married I stared to change my habit."
> - After their parents' death, they sold their house and went to another city and took all of the memories of that ___ with them."

PS:

In my country we call it "fatherhome".

Comment: Simply home.  Perhaps when describing it to others 'our house' or 'our home'.

Comment: @Icy, thanks, what if you don't live there anymore? Suppose you have visiting there after some years and are showing it to your son, and say " Ahh, good old day! This is my ----. We used to live here, I have many good memories from here.":)

Comment: Well, in some circumstances it would be "My parents' house."

Comment: "My old home" is idiomatic and often used to mean 'the home I grew up (or spent a significant amount of time) in'; in context, it doesn't literally mean the home is old (that is relative). "The house I grew up in" is also fine.

Comment: "my childhood home" or "the house of my childhood".

Comment: @Graffito, thanks, why don't you change your comment to a reply? :)

Comment: "The house where I grew up" is what I'd say. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=house+where+I+grew+up&year_start=1700&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chouse%20where%20I%20grew%20up%3B%2Cc0

Comment: @Graffito You beat me to it. You should definitely include *childhood home* as an answer.

Comment: Those terms you quote, *motherland*, *fatherland*, *mother tongue*, are not universal, but vary according to particular languages and ethnic cultures. In English the term *fatherland* is not much used.

Comment: Your attempt to keep your question has invalidated Rathony's answer, which I think is unfair. Your original question was practically the same as the older one, it is now, after the edit, relatively different.

Comment: The assumptions in your first sentence are wrong: some countries are motherlands and some fatherlands, but nobody has both.  See [Is it good practice to refer to countries using the feminine form?](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/12632/8019).

Comment: **Tharavaad**, we say in Malayalam, in south India. That is "childhood home"

Comment: I think @ hatchet and others have probably covered the most common references.  If I was visiting the house in the town where my family once lived, I would probably say "This was our family house/home".

Comment: What @Graffito said.

Comment: One does not compose general hypotheticals with *If X would, then Y would.* The first verb should be in the past, or with *were to*.

Comment: Thanks for your remark, @tchrist. I didn't know that. I will edit it. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think **family home** fits what you're looking for. According to [Google NGrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=family%20home%2Cchildhood%20home&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Cfamily%20home%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bfamily%20home%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BFamily%20Home%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cchildhood%20home%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bchildhood%20home%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BChildhood%20Home%3B%2Cc0), it's more common than "childhood home".

Example:
[Hugh Jackman tweet](https://twitter.com/realhughjackman/status/457988515335507968) "My family home growing up"

Answer (score 15):

Simply **my childhood home** (or "the house of my childhood").

> Example: *Lincoln was moved to write poetry after he returned to his
>   childhood home in Hardin County, Kentucky, in 1846, when he was a
>   thirty-seven-years-old Illinois lawyer*.

Comment: +1. As another example, the National Trust in the UK have also listed [the Beatles' Childhood Homes](http://www.nationaltrust.org.uk/beatles-childhood-homes) as places of interest on their site

Answer (score 4):

I don't think there is a suitable word for that other than my old place or house. However, The noun [birthplace](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/birthplace) is broadly used to indicate the place where people were born and raised in early childhood, especially for those who are historically famous.

[Abraham Lincoln's birthplace](https://www.nps.gov/abli/index.htm)

[George Washington's birthplace](https://www.nps.gov/gewa/index.htm)

[Source: National Park Service]

I think "the place where I was born (and raised when I was a child)" would be more idiomatic.

A side note: "[Place of birth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Place_of_birth)" is quite different from "birthplace" and you can visit the Wikipedia link and see the difference.